# How to handle timezone per user in web application using Quarkus or Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, quarkus

I try to add support for time zones to the web application. User's time zone will be used to display time and for calculations.

I checked a lot of blogs and posts on StackOverflow about Hibernate, Spring Boot related to time zones but I didn't found solution. Some posts describes using time zone only for displaying date/time to user but it's not enough. I need date time loaded from database with user time zone to make calculations on server.

I made some experiments with Hibernate Interceptors ([Hibernate user guide - Events](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events)). Hibernate gives ability to implement interceptor with `onLoad` method which allow to modify entity after load. In this case interceptor should modify date/time fields based on user time zone get from some global service. It looks like something I need but I don't have any experience with that on production and didn't know is it good way to solve the problem.

### Requirements

Each user should be able to set their own time zone.

The time zone is used not only for time display, but also for calculations. The application includes a booking module where the exact time is important. It cannot be that we allow someone to book an appointment, for example, at 10:00, because it is just 8:30 on the server, because it may already be 1:00 p.m., i.e. 3 hours after the appointment time in user's time zone.

### Problem

I would like to change time zone used by Hibernate for every HTTP request based on current user settings. How to set time zone that Hibernate uses during a given request?

### Tech stack

In the application I use Hibernate and the time is always saved in the database in UTC. On the application side, the time is converted to the time zone set in config (same time zone for every user).

I use Quarkus in the application, but the solution for Spring Boot is also satisfactory for me. Rewrite solution for Spring Boot or other Java EE framework to Quarkus will not be a problem for me.

### UPDATE 1

#### More context

Application is for photographers which can share booking page with their clients (and potential clients). I need to calculate available hours to reserve an appointment. Photographer can set up working hours like 8:00 - 16:00 in his/her time zone (e.g. Europe/Warsaw). In those hours clients can reserve appointments. Problem with using UTC on backend and using time zone only for display date/time starts when photographer use time zone with DST (Daylight Saving Time). In UTC 7:00 can be 8:00 in local time zone but it will be 9:00 during DST.

The same problem is when you try to send notifications like reminders about appointment. I need to know photographer time zone on server because I need to how much time remaining until appointment. For example in 20:00 UTC in time zone UTC+12 mean 8:00 next day. If I send reminder at 20:00 UTC with message like "You have appointment next day" it will wrong, because that client has appointment today.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is adding an HTTP interceptor to determine and setting the user time zone in the global context and then using a util class to perform date time operations. Is that a viable option for you or are you looking for a more generic solution?

Comment: Related: [*Pass browser timezone to the backend springboot application to generate reports with dates as per the browser timezone*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53496921/642706)

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu I tried with HTTP interceptor and separate service injected per request but it has one downside. I need to remember to always convert date/time loaded from database to user time zone. I'm looking for more generic solution, I want to avoid simple mistakes. Using separate utilclass I need to remember to use it in all places and can miss by mistake.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu I needed to split into two comments :) I'm looking for something similar to Ruby on Rails solution. They provide option to set up time zone for given request and ORM always use that time zone. ORM converts UTC to user time zone on loading data from database. I also think about Hibernate Interceptor to convert date/time to user time zone but I don't know is it good idea to do that. I will update question to add info about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Appointments are not moments

Appointments should not be kept as moments. An appointment booked in the future, when driven by a time-of-day, cannot be pinned down to a particular point on the timeline.

The reason is that political time is controlled by politicians. And those politicians can change the rules of the time zones under their jurisdiction on a whim at any moment. So if you try to nail down the moment of an appointment next January 23rd at 3 PM, you’ll be early or late when the [politicians decide to stay on Daylight Saving Time year-round](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/morocco-abolishes-time-changes.html). Or you’ll be a half-hour off when the [politicians decide to change their clock to match that of a neighbor](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-44010705) as a diplomatic gesture.

So you should keep appointments as a date with a time-of-day but keep the time zone separately. So *two* separate values.

- In Java that means a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`.
- In SQL that means one column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, and another column of a textual type for the name of the time zone.

When you need to build a schedule, you can determine a moment dynamically by combining the `LocalDateTime` with a `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime`. Do not store this result — it will not be valid when the politicians change the time zone rules.

Notice that the above is for appointments such as dentists and hair stylists and photographers, for appointments aimed at a particular time of the day. In contrast are plans tied to *natural* time such as a rocket launch scheduled according to expected weather conditions. Such plans are not altered by politicians changing the rules of a time zone. Such plans are recorded using a column of a type akin to SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, and Java type `Instant` (though exchanged with databases via the `OffsetDateTime` class).

I’ve posted on this before on Stack Overflow, as have others. Search to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simple and for some reason you have some over complicated situation.

If this was a `spring-mvc` application I would understood the need for UI-backend communication with some type of timezone. But you probably have a rest backend application since you are mentioning `quarkus` / `spring-boot`. Rest application is normally stateless.

I think that this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/time-zones-java-web-application/) from the very known **@vlad-mihalcea** also verifies what needs to be followed as best practice.  It concludes with what I also agree 100%.

> When dealing with time zones, it’s best to use UTC as much as possible
> and only convert the timestamp to the current user time zone when
> rendering the UI.

So I think your problem would be much simplified if you used UTC for database, UTC for backend server and you just used timezone in the UI just for the user to read it, by just converting from UTC to user's timezone. If you have the normal stateless rest application then the backend is completely agnostic for user timezone. The user lives in the browser window and so only the frontend knows about user timezone.

Even if we suppose that you need to remember the timezone of the user, then you can store the specific timezone for the user in database (user A has timezone GMT+2), and then the UI can poll it once and then convert all data it receives from backend to that timezone for that specific user.

So if you make calculations in the backend related with user `timezone` and you also persist timezones in Database, I would look at this as a probable architecture deficiency which will might overcomplicate the situation in the future even if you manage to solve your issue for the moment.

Comment: You have right in most cases converting UTC to local time can be done at frontend. In my case I need time zone not only for display date/time but also to calculate available hours. I added additional context to my question (under Update 1 title). Here is also interesting article about that problem: https://swizec.com/blog/saving-time-in-utc-doesnt-work-and-offsets-arent-enough/

Answer (score 1):

That:

> Hibernate gives ability to implement interceptor with onLoad method which allow to modify entity after load. In this case interceptor should modify date/time fields based on user time zone get from some global service. It looks like something I need but I don't have any experience with that on production and didn't know is it good way to solve the problem.

> I would like to change time zone used by Hibernate for every HTTP request based on current user settings. How to set time zone that Hibernate uses during a given request?

basically won't work, the problem is following:

**internal** representation of entity state in Hibernate is **array**, those arrays are stored in `EntityEntryContext` (SessionImpl.persistenceContext.entityEntryContext) and the purpose of those arrays is to check whether entities have been modified or not (dirty checking). When you get control over load process in `LoadEventListener#onLoad` entity state is already stored in `EntityEntryContext`, thus modifying entity will make it dirty from Hibernate perspective.

Flirting with "timezones" in persistence layer is bad idea.